# Type 'string' cannot be assigned to type 'UploadFileStatus | undefined'

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { Upload } from 'antd';
    import ImgCrop from 'antd-img-crop';

    interface uploadProps{
      fileList:string;

    }
    const UploadD:React.FC <uploadProps> = () => {
      const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([
        {
          uid: '-1',
          name: 'image.png',
          status: 'done',
          url: 'https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/jkjgkEfvpUPVyRjUImniVslZfWPnJuuZ.png',
        },
      ]);

      const onChange = ({ fileList: newFileList }) => {
        setFileList(newFileList);
      };

      const onPreview = async file => {
        let src = file.url;
        if (!src) {
          src = await new Promise(resolve => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file.originFileObj);
            reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
          });
        }
        const image = new Image();
        image.src = src;
        const imgWindow = window.open(src);
        imgWindow!.document.write(image.outerHTML);
      };

      return (
        <ImgCrop rotate>
          <Upload
            action="https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76"
            listType="picture-card"
            fileList={fileList}//this error:Type 'string' cannot be assigned to type 'UploadFileStatus | undefined'.
            onChange={onChange}
            onPreview={onPreview}
          >
            {fileList.length < 5 && '+ Upload'}
          </Upload>
        </ImgCrop>
      );
    };

    export default UploadD
```

**ERROR**

```
Type '{ uid: string; name: string; status: string; url: string; }[]' cannot be assigned to type 'UploadFile<any>[]'.
   Type '{ uid: string; name: string; status: string; url: string; }' cannot be assigned to type 'UploadFile<any>'.
     The types of property 'status' are incompatible.
       Type 'string' cannot be assigned to type 'UploadFileStatus | undefined'. ts(2322)
interface.d.ts(70, 5): Required type from property "fileList", on type "IntrinsicAttributes & UploadProps<any> & { children?: ReactNode; } & RefAttributes<any>" here
```

Comment: tip: use `URL.createObjectURL(file)` instead of using the `FileReader`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think because you are assigning `string` to `UploadFileStatus | undefined`.
`UploadFileStatus` can be one of `error | success | done | uploading | removed`.

Try to use the [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) :

```
const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([
        {
          uid: '-1',
          name: 'image.png',
          status: 'done' as UploadFileStatus,
          url: 'https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/jkjgkEfvpUPVyRjUImniVslZfWPnJuuZ.png',
        },
      ]);
```

Comment: Sure. Please use green tick to accept the answer and complete the question